# Eclipse 3.7.2 (64 bits) crash when using svn connector polarion 1.8.5

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, svn, 64-bit

I installed Eclipse 3.7.2 (64 bits) and update svn connector polarion 1.8.5. After that, I checked out project from svn successfully but I have 2 problems with Eclipse and svn information

1. Sometimes, Svn information of project does not show and I can't update or commit data
2. When I try to expand some folders from my project data, the Eclipse has been crashed.

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000342067997a, pid=31186, tid=1082423616
>
> JRE version: 6.0_27-b07
>
> Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.2-b06 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>
> Problematic frame:
>
> C  [libc.so.6+0x7997a]  short+0x3a
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>
> /users/jimmy/hs_err_pid31186.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>
> ```
>   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
> ```

Please help me to find out the problems

Comment: Your java version is pretty old. Try updating to Java 7 or Java 8.